# How should I go about making a barcode reader app using Xcode

Tags: xcode, barcode

I was just wondering the steps that I need to take to develop a Barcode Scanning app with Xcode considering that I am new to programming with Xcode.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the ZBar iOS sdk - it's pretty useful and a good library to use. 
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/